# Getting True/False Result from MySql Query for Multiple Values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a data table setup with columns:

```
id
person
theDate
```

Each row will represent a checkin from `person` and the date that the person checked in. Each checkin will be a new row, and there will never be more than one checkin per day per person.

What I am trying to achieve is a MySQL query that can do the following:

1. Check to see if there is a row from yesterday `WHERE person='BOB' AND theDate=subdate(CURDATE(), 1)` and if there is a row, return `true`, otherwise, return `false`.
2. Check to see if there is a row from two days ago `WHERE person='BOB' AND theDate=subdate(CURDATE(), 2)` and if there is a row, return `true`, otherwise, return `false`.
3. Check to see if there is a row from today `WHERE person='BOB' AND theDate=CURDATE()` and if there is a row, return `true`, otherwise, return `false`.

I realize I can just do three separate queries and do a row count and store the result to a variable; however, I think it would be more efficient for a single query.

The requirement for boolean is not fixed either. A `1` instead of `true` will do just as well.

My guess would be to do the following, but it obviously does not work:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT('id') FROM timecard WHERE theDate = subdate(CURDATE(), 1)) as yesterday, (SELECT COUNT('id') FROM timecard WHERE theDate = subdate(CURDATE(), 2)) as twodays , (SELECT COUNT('id') FROM timecard WHERE theDate = CURDATE()) as today
```

Comment: while it can be done in a query. does it make sense to put all the logic on to the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select sum(theDate = subdate(CURDATE(), 2)) > 0 as two_days_ago,
       sum(theDate = subdate(CURDATE(), 1)) > 0 as yesterday,           
       sum(theDate = CURDATE()) > 0 as today
from your_table
where person = 'BOB'
```

Comment: Tested it out and it works exactly as I needed. Thanks. But, just so I can learn, I know that when I `sum` by a column, it gives me the sum of that column, but doing `sum` of an expression is confusing me a bit. Is it doing a mini `WHERE` inside each sum?

Comment: The condition inside the sum() evaluates to `true` or `false` which is `1` and `0` in MySQL. It sums up those `1`s and checks if at least one time the condition was true with `>0`